# AngularJS : Use factory inside a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I use angularjs seed and trying to write a simple factory and insert it in to the controller.

I have a Row factory definition

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('Row', [ function () {
 return 'some string';
 ); 
}])
```

inside my view1 controller I have

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/view1', {
templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
controller: 'View1Ctrl'
});
}])

.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', 'Row', function($scope, Row) {
}]);
```

And I am getting an error it's not finding the Row factory.

Answer (score 1):

Your factory should be  using `myApp.view1` module as `myApp` module is not defined.

```
angular.module('myApp.view1')
.factory('Row', [function() {
    return 'some string';
}])
```

**Update**

If you wanted to create a new module and append factory to it, then you should create a new module and include the previous dependency inside the `[]` array.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.view1'])
.factory('Row', [function() {
    return 'some string';
}])
```

Note: this JS should be loaded after the factory JS in order to make `myApp.view1` available.

---

It seems like you are returning only string value form your factory. I'd say rather than having factory, you could make `constant`/ `value`. Out of which making `constant` would be preferred way of doing it. As it will be available in config phase as well.

```
angular.module('myApp.view1')
.constant('Row', 'some string');
```

Comment: one extra close parenthesis is there strike it out

Comment: I change it to 'myApp.view1' but I am still getting an error.

Unknown provider: RowProvider <- Row <- View1Ctrl

Answer (score 0):

Tell "myApp.view1" to use "myApp".

```
angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute', 'myApp'])
```